# NoRouteToHostException while using Gmail API

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I have been conscientiously following the steps to configure the usage of the Gmail API on a Java project (test automation).

- OAuth2 credentials = OK (for a desktop app, as specified)
- All methods are from a pretty recentish tutorial based on the official docs https://github.com/swtestacademy/gmail-tutorial

When I launch the project, a window opens and asks me for permission to use the Gmail API. I validate this and I'm redirected to a screen that says that the verification code was sent and that I can close the window. I close it, but then I realize that an error was thrown:

`Exception log java.net.NoRouteToHostException`

OS: Ubuntu
Browser: Chrome 71 (last stable version for Ubuntu...)

I have been changing the port (8888 to 80 an other ones) but with no success.
The credentials are ok (I've been trying with other ones but it fails opening the permission window in the first place)

Any help will be appreciated.

The code is:

```
public class GmailRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GmailService service = new GmailService();
        System.out.println("Total count of emails is :"+service.getTotalCountOfMails());
        boolean exist = service.isMailExist("Coolblue invoice");
        System.out.println("Mail 'Security Alert' title exist or not: " + exist);
        exist = service.isMailExist("BLABLA");
        System.out.println("Mail 'Security Alert' title exist or not: " + exist);
    }
}
```

GmailService class:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListMessagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Thread;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class GmailService {

    private static final String user = "me";
    private final String APPLICATION_NAME = "TEST";
    private final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH;
    /**
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
    private String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH;

    public GmailService() {

        TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                File.separator + "src" +
                File.separator + "main" +
                File.separator + "resources" +
                File.separator + "credential";
        CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") +
                File.separator + "src" +
                File.separator + "main" +
                File.separator + "resources" +
                File.separator + "credential" +
                File.separator + "credentials.json";

    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     *
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH));
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    private List<Message> getMessages(ListMessagesResponse response) {
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
            while (response.getMessages() != null) {
                messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
                if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                    String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                    response = service.users().messages().list(user)
                            .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return messages;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception log " + e);
            return messages;
        }
    }

    public int getTotalCountOfMails() {
        int size;
        try {
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build(); // *** ATTENTION PLEASE :D This is when the error occurs ***
            List<Thread> threads = service.
                    users().
                    threads().
                    list("me").
                    execute().
                    getThreads();
             size = threads.size();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception log " + e);
            size = -1;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isMailExist(String messageTitle) {
        try {
            final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .build();
            ListMessagesResponse response = service.
                    users().
                    messages().
                    list("me").
                    setQ("subject:" + messageTitle).
                    execute();
            List<Message> messages = getMessages(response);
            return messages.size() != 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception log" + e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely caused by a network issue as the `NoRouteToHostException` error documentation states:

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

The code itself shouldn't be the problem, I'd suggest checking your own internet connection as that may be the reason of the error message.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply but I don't know how to troubleshoot this one; the internet connection is ok for everything else...

Comment: I guess it was a proxy problem, which is solved now.